# Will a `if` or `return` quit early if the condition is fulfilled?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if a `if` statement or a `return`quits early if possible. E.g. in this code:

```
bool Point::operator==(const Point &rhs) const
{
  return (x==rhs.x //if the x's are not equal, there's no point in comparing y and z.
          && y==rhs.y
          && z==rhs.z);
}
```

or this:

```
bool Point::operator==(const Point &rhs) const
{
  if (x==rhs.x //same as above
      && y==rhs.y
      && z==rhs.z)
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

Further, is any one of the above version better?

Comment: Concerning your last question, there is a very strong chance that your optimizer will translate both forms into the exact same code.

Comment: *"is any one of the above version better?"*. Style preference.

Comment: TL;DR: Yes, `&&` and `||` will return early.